# Trying to have multiple command files for Discord bot

Tags: javascript, file, discord, discord.js

Question: Is there any way to have multiple command files for a discord bot?

What I mean by "command file" is the file that contains the if/else statements and commands for the users to actually interact with.

What I mean by "multiple files" is making more than one of these "command files" that can respond to commands.

I'm trying to split my fun and admin commands into 2 separate files but currently only one is working. I know that one of the problems lie in the package.json file where it says: "main": "index.js",

```
{
  "name": "n00bly783",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.2.1",
    "discord.js-commando": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to connect a single package.json file to multiple other .js files? And if so, is that all I need to do to get multiple discord bot .js files to start working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to edit the package .json.

To use multiple files, you can simply do the following:

(commandfile1.js)

```
module.exports = {
  commandName: {
    variableToCallToRunFunction: (arguments) => { //usually called run
      //the command
    }
  }
}
```

(mainfile.js)

```
commandfile1 = require('./commandfile1.js') //if commandfile1 is in the same folder as this file
yourBot.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith(yourPrefix){
    cmdmsg = msg.content.replace(yourprefix, '')
    for (command in commandfile1){
      if (cmdmsg.startsWith(commandfile1[command])){
        commandfile1[command].variableToCallToRunFunction(arguments) //usually just .run()
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

This is one way to do it, all you have to do is export the separate command file as an object, and make every command a separate entry in the object. Then every time a message is sent with your bots' prefix in front of it, cycle through all of the commands and run the one the user specified.

Comment: Even with this method, it still forces me to still have a bunch of if/else statements on a single page?